# Python string formatting and UUID

Tags: python, xml, pandas, csv, uuid

I am attempting to read in CSV data and map it to the following XML structure. In my first attempt, I have used % operator for string formatting, which works.

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid
df = pd.read_csv('media.csv', sep=',')
def convert_row(row):
   return """<video>
    <videoType fileUID="%s" name="">
        <locationType></locationType>
        <type>%s</type>
        <format>%s</format>
        <year>%s</year>
    </videoType>
</video>""" % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])


print '\n'.join(df.apply(convert_row, axis=1))
```

However, I am hoping to populate the `fileUID="%s"` with a generated uuid, that I can then reference elsewhere. I'm not able to get this to work.

I tried adding `u = str(uuid.uuid4())` just before the return statement and update `% (u, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])`

I get a 'not all arguments converted during string formatting' error

So I attempted to use f-strings formatting

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid
df = pd.read_csv('media.csv', sep=',')
def convert_row(row):
   return f"""<video>
    <videoType fileUID="{u}" name="">
        <locationType></locationType>
        <type>{row[0]}</type>
        <format>{row[1]}</format>
        <year>{row[2]}</year>
    </videoType>
</video>"""


print '\n'.join(df.apply(convert_row, axis=1))
```

and get another error stating invalid syntax in regards to the closing `"""`

I guess my questions are which string formatting style is the best option when dealing with UUID and what is wrong with my code? Plus, if I wish to reference the generated uuid in other generated xml structures - I will ultimately create an xml file with the multiple generated xml structure content.

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: @jezrael That doesn't matter.

Comment: I still get the same error = invalid syntax in regards to the closing `"""`

Comment: *"not all arguments converted during string formatting"* – Well, as far as we can see, you have 4 `%s` in the string but you're passing 5 values in `% (...)`. So, yeah, that would explain that.

Comment: @deceze thank you, I thought I had removed the extra in '% (...)` - so frustrating. If wish to generate another xml structure and reference to a generated FUID (uuid) - how would be best to do this? or should I create a separate question?

Comment: @user3927287 you might want to look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents - that way you're not working with string formatting and won't have to worry about any escaping/encoding required for any attributes you apply to the the tags/text elements etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @deceze's point you were missing some formatting in your code shown.

I believe what your looking for is something like this?

## Code

```python
"""UUID Example."""
import pandas as pd
import uuid

df = pd.read_csv('media.csv', sep=',')


def convert_row(row):
    """Convert Row Example."""
    u = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return """<video>
    <videoType fileUID={} name=\"\">
        <locationType></locationType>
        <type>{}</type>
        <format>{}</format>
        <year>{}</year>
    </videoType>
</video>""".format(u, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])

print("\n".join(df.apply(convert_row, axis=1)))
```

## Results

```bash
$ python3 uuid_testing.py 
<video>
    <videoType fileUID=d07ea048-a08f-444c-9182-7fff3a825dcc name="">
        <locationType></locationType>
        <type>2</type>
        <format>b</format>
        <year>f</year>
    </videoType>
</video>
<video>
    <videoType fileUID=4b058e99-457e-4b26-ac03-593c51e6cb1e name="">
        <locationType></locationType>
        <type>3</type>
        <format>c</format>
        <year>g</year>
    </videoType>
</video>
<video>
    <videoType fileUID=8d04f6e6-1b5b-4103-a42a-aaa9c45d7bc5 name="">
        <locationType></locationType>
        <type>4</type>
        <format>d</format>
        <year>h</year>
    </videoType>
</video>
```

**Github:** [Code was added to my Repo.](https://github.com/JayRizzo/Random_Scripts/blob/master/uuid_testing.py)